# Shiny app: Can't plot stock chart based on user input

Tags: r, plot, shiny, quantmod

I am trying to plot a stock chart using quantmod in a shiny app but I get the following error: input$stockInput download failed after two attempts. Error message: HTTP error 404. Any help is appreciated.

**Server:**

```
library(quantmod)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    price <- getSymbols('input$stockInput',from='2017-01-01')
    plot(price)

})})
```

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Stock Chart"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

       #This is a dropdown to select the stock
       selectInput("stockInput", 
                   "Pick your stock:", 
                   c("AMZN","FB","GOOG","NVDA","AAPL"),
                   "AMZN"),selected = "GOOG"),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot")
))))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code requires a few changes. First when you are accessing a shiny UI object in `server.R` you should use it as an object not as a quoted character

`price <- getSymbols(input$stockInput,from='2017-01-01')`

And the function `getSymbols` without a value set to the argument (`auto.assign = F`) creates a new xts object in the stock name whose data is requested and so in the below code I've used it with setting `auto.assign = F` so it becomes easier to access the object `price` for plotting. Otherwise, you might have to fetch the value inside `price` using `get()` and then plot them as I've commented.

#### server.R

```
library(quantmod)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    price <- getSymbols(input$stockInput,from='2017-01-01', auto.assign = F)
    #plot(get(price), main = price) #this is used when auto.assign is not set by default which is TRUE
    plot(price, main = input$stockInput) # this is when the xts object is stored in the name price itself

  })})
```

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Stock Chart"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      #This is a dropdown to select the stock
      selectInput("stockInput", 
                  "Pick your stock:", 
                  c("AMZN","FB","GOOG","NVDA","AAPL"),
                  "AMZN"),selected = "GOOG"),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    ))))
```

Hope it clarifies!